# Has something been recently done to speed up Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, performance

In the past month or so, I've noticed that Stack Exchange sites have loaded in a half a heartbeat. I remember times when I had to wait for certain pages to load. Yet lately, everything I do has been instantaneous.

Great job, whatever you did.

But I'm just wondering what it is that you did to speed everything up?

Comment: They started deleting more "comedy hour" comments

Comment: That would make sense. Although I'd expect that to be one tiny percentage of the issues.

Comment: I remember they put the SO database on a seperate database server some time ago, separate from the other sites.

Comment: There was mention somewhere that the code for comments got refactored, so that might be helping.

Comment: They started caching.

Comment: They've been doing work on improving miniprofiler, making it more flexible and able to measure cache times in a more detailed way so maybe that has improved things. That or they got some faster unicorns.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Definitely the latter. All other optimization talk is definitely a lie.

Comment: These are indeed some really fast unicorns.